# change calendar view not to go to the current month

Tags: calendar, view

We have separate Calendar lists for each year in order to aid with archiving.

This means however that for previous years, you'd have to navigate back a few years to get any events to show up.

We would like to have the current year's calendar show the current month (easily done by default functionality) and have previous years' calendars show January of that year.

We've found this "CalendarDate" GET query that can set the current month like we want, but it doesn't seem to work properly as no events show up until you use the OOTB calendar navigation.

1. is it possible to have it default to show a certain month rather than the current month?
2. if it's not, is there a really easy way to archive a whole year away so that the calendar doesn't grow indefinitely?

related links:

http://thedotnetter.wordpress.com/2011/09/27/specifying-the-start-date-and-time-period-in-the-url-to-a-sharepoint-calendar-using-out-of-the-box-functionality/

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8140402/navigate-to-day-in-sharepoint-calendar